# How to skip part of method code in Rails specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got this method

```
def finalize_inquiry_process(form)
  if finalize_process == true
    inquiry_process.campaign_code.update(state: 'used')
    document_creator_class = InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(inquiry_process).call
    document_creator_class.new(inquiry_process).call
  end
  Success(form)
end
```

and I want to skip in specs this part which is really trouble maker, implementation is an unnecessary waste of time (pdf generator with tons of fields)

```
document_creator_class = InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(inquiry_process).call
document_creator_class.new(inquiry_process).call
```

To do so I wrote a specs:

```
  let(:fetcher_instance) { instance_double(InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher) }

  before do
    allow(InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher).to receive(:new).and_return(fetcher_instance)
    allow(fetcher_instance).to receive(:call).and_return(nil)
  end

  it 'updates state of assigned campain code' do
    updated_inquiry_process = process_update.value!
    expect(updated_inquiry_process.campaign_code.state).to eq('used')
  end
end
```

> InquiryProcesses::Update.call campain code updates state of assigned campain code
>        Failure/Error: document_creator_class.new(inquiry_process).call
>
> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Is there any chance to skip this part of code in specs?

Comment: Personally, I would move that code to another method and just stub that method on your test. Usually, it's better to avoid stubbing a chain of method, because your test ends up depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed it by using `receive_message_chain` helper. Specs should looked like this:

```
describe 'finalize inquiry process' do
  subject(:process_update) do
    described_class.new(
      inquiry_process: inquiry_process,
      form: loan_application_inquiry_process_update_form,
      finalize_process: true,
    ).call
  end

  let!(:inquiry_process) do
    create :inquiry_process, inquiry_template: loan_inquiry_template, campaign_code_uid: campaign_code.uid
  end

  before do
    allow(InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher).to receive_message_chain(:new, :call, :new, :call)
  end

  it 'updates state of assigned campain code' do
    updated_inquiry_process = process_update.value!
    expect(updated_inquiry_process.campaign_code.state).to eq('used')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try your luck with dependency injection: 
(It's a rough sketch, but I don't know the context of the system, not even the whole class)

```
def initialize(inquiry_process:, form:, finalize_process:,  creator_fetcher:) 
  @creator_fetcher = creator_fetcher
  # all the other initializetions
  # maybe you can initialize creator_fetcher outside, and no need to pass inquiry_process anymore?
end

def creator_fetcher
  @creator_fetcher ||= InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(inquiry_process)
end

def finalize_inquiry_process(form)
  if finalize_process == true
    inquiry_process.campaign_code.update(state: 'used')
    document_creator_class = creator_fetcher.call
    document_creator_class.new(inquiry_process).call
  end
  Success(form)
end
```

and then

```
let(:creator_fetcher) { instance_double(InquiryProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher) }
let(:document_creator_class) { instance_double(whatever_fetcher_call_returns_or_just_unveryfying_double) }

before { allow(creator_fetcher.to_receive(:call).and_return(document_creator_class) }

subject(:process_update) do
  described_class.new(
    inquiry_process: inquiry_process,
    form: loan_application_inquiry_process_update_form,
    finalize_process: true,
  ).call
end
```

Anyway - your problems with tests show's that your code was not written with the tests, and it's a bad design.

Indirection (Dependency Injection here) might help a little to untangle the mess.